# Sorting An array in Protractor

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sorting, protractor

I am using protractor for my E2E testcases.
In my case, I am having an array and I want to sort it

Ex.

```
Arraylist.push(elements[1].getText());

Arraylist.push(elements[2].getText());

Arraylist.push(elements[0].getText());
```

`element[n]` is returning a text value which is getting inserted into the ArrayList.
Now I want to Sort this Array and test that the elements are in the correct order.

Do someone has idea, How can we do that?

Comment: Can you clarify why you would like to print the sorted values? My understanding of E2E tests using Protractor is that the output are is successful `expect`ations.

Comment: My testcase is to compare that whenever user click on header of an list, the items under it should be sorted.                                  Therefore I  am  inserting each element in an array so that I can sort that array too and compare with the sorted list on UI.

Comment: I've edited the question so your requirements are clearer. Feel free to amend if I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you should be aware that all the elements and return values of `getText()` are promises. Therefore sorting the array, and comparing the sorted with the unsorted, has to be done with the resolved results of these promises.

```
var unsorted = elements.map(function(element) {
  return element.getText();
});

var sorted = unsorted.then(function(texts) {
  // Make sure to copy the array to not sort the original
  return texts.slice(0).sort();
});

var equals = protractor.promise.all([unsorted, sorted]).then(function(texts) {
  var unsorted = texts[0];
  var sorted = texts[1];
  var allEqual = (unsorted.length === sorted.length);
  sorted.forEach(function(sortedItem, i) {
    allEqual = allEqual && (sortedItem === unsorted[i]);
  });
  return allEqual;
});

expect(equals).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what the connection to E2E testing or protractor is, but well ...  Arraylist.sort() or use lodash/underscorejs _.sortBy(Arraylist, sortingValue)